# Javascript/Angular2 How can I toggle button based on the form field values

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-forms

I have a form with mandatory fields as -
1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Phone
4. State
5. City
6. Date of Birth
 I have a button which should toggle to complete/Incomplete based on the form inputs.The button should toggle to  'complete' only when all the fields have proper values.If I remove any of the value again,the button should toggle to Incomplete.

In my ts file-

```
formCompleteOrIncomplete(person,index) {
   if (person.dateOfBirth !== "" && person.phone!== "" &&
      (person.firstName !== undefined || person.firstName !== "") && (person.lastName !== undefined || person.lastName !== "") && (person.state !== undefined || person.state !== "") && (person.city !== undefined || person.city !== "" )) {      
      person.status = true;

    }
    else {
      person.status = false;      
    }
}
```

In my html file-

```
<div class="tag">
   <div class="success" *ngIf="person.status">Complete</div>
   <div class="failed" *ngIf="!person.status">Incomplete</div>
</div>
```

form fields-

```
   <md-input required [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" (ngModelChange) = "formCompleteOrIncomplete(person, index)" aria-placeholder="First Name" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" #firstName="ngModel"></md-input>
```

On page load the button shows 'Incomplete' as none of the field values are entered and when I enter all the fields, button is getting toggled to 'Complete' but when I try to empty any of the field again, it does not get toggled to 'Incomplete' again.

Also, when i do not include a check for 'undefined' and include only "" check, on page load the button shows 'complete'.NOt sure why is this happening.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: you can set a boolean value to check it the formControl is valid or not if it is valid you change the button value to complete or true or else incomplete or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your problem is in the parts of your `if` statement that are using the `||` (or) operator. They should be using the `&&` (and) operator as you don't want them to be either of those values to be filled in. When you change the first name field to be empty after you filled in the rest of the fields, the first part of the check will pass because an empty string is not `undefined`.

You should be able to clean that up a bit since you are checking for falsey values in both parts of your checks on the form fields. An empty string, `undefined`, and `null` will all convert to a `false` boolean value (you can check it out in your console by putting `!` (not) operators before the value and see that when converted to a boolean, each will be `false` - i.e. `!''` will convert the empty string to a boolean value and then do a not operation, so you will see `true` in your console).

```js
formCompleteOrIncomplete(person,index) {
    // Inverted the order of your true/false portions to match if statement
    if (!person.dateOfBirth || !person.phone || !person.firstName ||
        !person.lastName || !person.state || !person.city) {
        person.status = false;
    }
    else {
        person.status = true;
    }
    
    // Or you could do this to keep the same structure of your if statement
    if (!!person.dateOfBirth && !!person.phone && !!person.firstName &&
        !!person.lastName && !!person.state && !!person.city) {
        person.status = true;
    }
    else {
        person.status = false;
    }
    
    // You could even set the status using your check if you feel comfortable doing that
    person.status =
        !!person.dateOfBirth && !!person.phone && !!person.firstName &&
        !!person.lastName && !!person.state && !!person.city;
}
```

Comment: Well explained! Changing the OR operator to AND worked.I also had to check for undefined and empty check together.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `formCompleteorIncomplete` function or `ngModel, ngModelChange etc...`.

You should use angular2's [ReactiveForms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html). `ReactiveForms` are the preferred approach to working with forms.

like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form= this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required ],// <--- set any validators here
      lastName: ['', Validators.required ],
      ...//and so on...
      })
    });
```

Next, add a formControlName:

```
<md-input required formControlName="firstName" aria-placeholder="First Name" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName"></md-input>
```

finally, you can toggle buttons with `form.valid` like so:
(form.valid changes depending on whether the form is valid (based on the **validators** you set above).

```
<div class="tag">
   <div class="success" *ngIf="form.valid">Complete</div>
   <div class="failed" *ngIf="!form.valid">Incomplete</div>
</div>
```

[Check this site out for an example.](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html)